# Wordpress Delay of up to 2 minutes page response time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows

We have an application that we inherited which is written in WordPress on a Windows server.

The dedicated server we have has 8 cores with 8GB memory. When we analyse the processor/CPU/Memory they all seem to be running along nicely.

However, each page request is taking anything from 10 seconds to 2 minutes to respond.

In Chrome's developer tools we can see the response times. Once the site responds the time to download all the elements on the page is around 1 second and the forwarding time from http -> https is around 30ms .

That eliminates IIS from being slow and from the page resources from being slow.

We have tuned MySQL (innodb_buffer_pool_size 2GB and innodb_thread_concurrency unlimited) and a simple (non wordpress) page with a MySQL call loads almost instantly so this eliminates MySQL itself as the problem.

We have disabled as many plugins as we can but the problem still happens.

The problem is happening throughout the day.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem on our website. We used a caching plugin and it made a huge difference. Check out WP Super Cache.